# Is it posible to emulate an samsung s9 on windows

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to find a way to emulate an samsung s9 on my pc. I have been looking amd can’t find an answer to this question. I hope someone on here knows the answer and if isit possible can tell me how to set it up.

Answer (score -1):

use a program called "Nox", look up how to set the phone to the S9